# Dynamic web database scraping in Python

Tags: python, calendar, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Anyone have any idea what's wrong with the below code? It grabs the data from one day only. The webpage is however a dynamic web database and contains data for a number of years. I need to scrape the data for each month and day within 2013-2016 and store into a CSV file.

```
import calendar
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cal = calendar.Calendar()

base_url = 'http://www.pse.pl/index.php?modul=21&id_rap=24&data=2016'
month_url = '&Month='
day_url = '&Day='

for year in range(2015, 2017):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        monthdays = [d for d in cal.itermonthdays(year, month) if d != 0]
        for day in monthdays:
            r = requests.get(base_url + str(year) + month_url + str(month) + day_url + str(day))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
            findtable = soup.find('table',{'id':'tabela'})
            for i in findtable.findAll('tr'):
                for j in i.findAll('td'):
                    print (j.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing I noticed is that the date must be formatted differently in the url that you send to the site. Hyphens are required between elements of the date (year, month and day). I can also suggest an easier way of moving through the days.

**Arrows** is a module for working with dates. In this case I use it for generating a range of days from 1 January 2015 through 3 January 2015 inclusive.

I also use it for formatting these dates.

I find the tables using BeautifulSoup and then use pandas for extracting the contents of the tables into a dataframe. Finally, I write those dataframes into csv files.

```
>>> import requests
>>> import arrow
>>> import bs4
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> start = arrow.get(datetime(2015,1,1))
>>> end = arrow.get(datetime(2015,1,3))
>>> base_url = 'http://www.pse.pl/index.php?modul=21&id_rap=24&data='
>>> for day in arrow.Arrow.range('day', start, end):
...     page = requests.get(base_url+day.format('YYYY-MM-DD')).content
...     soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
...     table = soup.find('table' ,{'id':'tabela'})
...     df = pd.read_html(str(table))
...     df[0].to_csv(day.format('YYYY-MM-DD')+'.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like the way you modified my code. I think I understand how it works. I added below a further issue you may probably know how to solve.

Comment: @taumar: You should, please, ask this as a separate question. (Let me know when you do and I will offer an answer if no-one else does.) In all likelihood, the real pandas experts here on SO will be able to give you a much better answer than I can.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to "click" on site with `BeautifulSoup`.

In this case I see 2 options:

1) Explore `selenium` module to interact with the site.

2) Notice that links are of such style:

`http://www.pse.pl/index.php?modul=21&id_rap=24&data=2017-07-19`. Interetsing part here is **&data=2017-07-19**

You can build a loop that passes a concrete date to the tail of base link and open each of such links with `requests`. And parsing goes further.